# Why does setlocale() in php throw this warn message?

Tags: php

Hey i'm working on a website at the moment and wanna remove this warn message.
Google don't help me so i started to search here and still not found a working solution.

> Error: setlocale(): Invalid locale category name LC_MESSAGES, must be
>   one of LC_ALL, LC_COLLATE, LC_CTYPE, LC_MONETARY, LC_NUMERIC, or
>   LC_TIME

my code:

```
$locale = 'de_DE';
setlocale("LC_MESSAGES",$locale );
```

If i replace LC_Messages with LC_All or something from the upper solutions my website isn't working anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: remove quotes  of "LC_MESSAGES"

Comment: `LC_MESSAGES` isn't always supported: _LC_MESSAGES for system responses (available if PHP was compiled with libintl)_. Source: [PHP: setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

Comment: @Anant next error is: Notice: Use of undefined constant LC_MESSAGES - assumed 'LC_MESSAGES'

Comment: @xNiceEinz Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around LC_MESSAGES.

```
$locale = 'de_DE';
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES,$locale );
```

For more information on how to use this function, refer the documentation at
[setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

Apparently LC_MESSAGES isn't always supported.

You can run

```
locale
```

on your terminal if you're using a linux distribution to find the list of constants supported.

Comment: The quotes aren't the problem. Thank you anyway.

Comment: next error ist: "Notice: Use of undefined constant LC_MESSAGES - assumed 'LC_MESSAGES'"

Comment: `setlocale()` docs state: "LC_MESSAGES for system responses (available if PHP was compiled with libintl)" so it must not be available in your PHP setup.

Comment: I assume you're not using a windows environment.
You can run `locale` on the terminal and find the available constants for LC_*

Answer (score 0):

LC_MESSAGES is an environment variable, it should not be enclosed in strings.

Instead use

```
$locale = 'de_DE';
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES,$locale );
```

This should help. And please check that libintl is there in your setup. For windows you can get it [libintl for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libintl.htm)

Answer (score 0):

LC_MESSAGES isn't always supported: LC_MESSAGES for system responses (available if PHP was compiled with libintl). Source: PHP: setlocale